# Testing Google Play Service API with Robolectric

Tags: android, unit-testing, google-play-services, robolectric, google-fit

I am working on an app that is using the Google Fit API.

I am using Robolectric for my unit testing.

I can't find anywhere examples of how to Mock the Google Play API so In can test my class with out writing actually data to Fit.

Answer (score 0):

This is how we exclude Google Analytics API from Robolectric test run. Maybe it can also be applied to Google Fit API (by changing analytics namespace to fit namespace)?

```
public class YourTestApplication extends YourApplication
    implements TestLifecycleApplication {

    ...

    @Override
    public void beforeTest(Method method) {
        ShadowApplication shadowApplication = Robolectric.shadowOf(Robolectric.application);
        shadowApplication.declareActionUnbindable("com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START");
    }

    ...

}
```

Reference: http://robolectric.blogspot.sg/2013/04/the-test-lifecycle-in-20.html